# How much computing power(Server Resource) i need to run my taxi app?

Tags: server, web-development, web-server

i have **140 drivers & 200+ not more than 300 bookings from passengers** within 24 hours. So, i want to **deploy my taxi app on a cloud server**. Same uber concept but this one is using taxi. **Can someone recommend me the amount of computing power i need to run this taxi app for a smooth transaction in a month. Like the amount of Ram, Storage, CPU's etc** etc.

Um using PHP LARAVEL 7, SQL XAMPP, CSS, HTML.

Your help is highly appreciated. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Server resource not only depends on its user, but also upon which language it was written in.
For example a simple PHP Application can run with just < 100 MB of RAM. But  a Java application (Spring Boot) requires >200 MB for an sample app.

For roughly calculating the RAM requirements, run the application with just 10 users (drivers or passengers) and note down the difference between the RAM usage when idle vs 10 users & divide by 10. You will get RAM Usage for 1 user. Then multiply it by the number of users.

But this method will not work for the CPU recommendations. So specify the programming language your application was written in.

Comment: Um using PHP 7 & MySQL database. Currently running on Windows Server 2016.